# Magnitude of a complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have this DTFT of an impulse response in a DSP course

$H(\omega) ~=~ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h[n]\, e^{-j \omega n} ~=~ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha^n\, e^{-j \omega n} ~=~ \sum_{n=0}^\infty ( \alpha\, e^{-j \omega})^n ~=~ \frac{1}{1 - \alpha e^{-j \omega} }$

They then state that the magnitude of

$H(\omega)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha e^{-j\omega}}$

is

$\left | H(\omega )\right |^2=\frac{1}{1+\alpha^2 -2\alpha cos(\omega)}$

I cannot see how. Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried to compute $| H(\omega ) |^2$, using $|z|^2 = z \overline z$ ?

Comment: I lost some hours on this before coming here to ask...

Answer (score 1):

That follows from
$$
|1 - z|^2 = (1 - z)(1 - \overline z) = 1 - (z + \overline z) + z \overline z
 = 1 - 2 \, \text{Re} (z) + |z|^2
$$
for any complex number $z$.