# Can anyone explain how the $\text{(magnitude)}^2$ can be calculated with multiplying $\frac{1}{1-ae^{jw}}$ from this DTFT?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, discrete-time

Can anyone explain how the $(\text{magnitude})^2$ can be calculated with multiplying $\frac{1}{1-ae^{jw}}$ from this DTFT?

[Provided here. Kindly click in to see the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vBYF.png)

Comment: The magnitude squared of what and by multiplying what?

Comment: Did you click into the image? Why (1/(ae^(-jw))) is multiple with (1/(ae^(jw))) to get (magnitude)^2?

Comment: $z\bar{z} = \vert z\vert ^2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magnitude of a complex exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598915/magnitude-of-a-complex-exponential)

Comment: I assumed that those calculations were yours so was confused as to what you were asking. The answer to your question then is your own calculations.

Comment: @Tim Can you elaborate a bit more? Since this is in fraction can also applied the formula you provided?

Comment: @Paul This is a calculation from my lecturer

Comment: @AYW That link has the answer of yours. Please read first. Then state which part you dont understand and provides attempts in your question.

Comment: @Tim According to the provided link, is |H(w)|^2=1/(|1-z|^2)? The confusing part for me is this as |1-z|^2 is just the denominator part of |H(w)|.

Comment: @AYW Yes, as $\left\vert\frac{1}{z}\right\vert=\frac{1}{\vert z \vert}$, you can replace with $1-z$

Comment: @Tim Alright! Thanks a lot